# Ansible is using wrong version of Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ansible, raspberry-pi

I have been dealing with this issue for a couple of days now.  I am running ansible on a raspberry pi.  I have made Python3.7 the default version of Python.  Apparently Ansible wants to use Python 2.7.  I have added Version 3.7 in the vars in the playbook but this does not change the module location.  It still looks for the modules in Python 2.7.

I am not sure how to tell Ansible to use 3.7 for all the modules and the interpreter.

```
pi@pi:~ $ python --version
Python 3.7.2
pi@pi:~ $ ansible-playbook vm.yaml -vv
ansible-playbook 2.9.6
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/pi/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.7.16 (default, Oct 10 2019, 22:02:15) [GCC 8.3.0]
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

PLAYBOOK: vm.yaml *************************************************************************************************************************************
1 plays in vm.yaml

PLAY [localhost] **********************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/pi/vm.yaml:12
ok: [localhost]
META: ran handlers

TASK [Gather info about the vmware guest vm] ******************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/pi/vm.yaml:28
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyVim'
fatal: [localhost -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (PyVmomi) on pi's Python /usr/bin/python3. Please read module documentation and install in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter"}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

pi@pi:~ $
```

Comment: You have to install Ansible pre-configured to use Python3. Your solution would consequentially involve a reinstall.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You probably need to change this.

```
ansible-playbook 2.9.6
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/pi/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.7.16 (default, Oct 10 2019, 22:02:15) [GCC 8.3.0]
```

`python version` is defined as 2.7.16, which you need to change.

Comment: Yes I know.  I understand what I need to change, my question is where do I change it at?  /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg is mostly all commented out.

Comment: Use the find function in a text editor and hopefully you will find it.

Answer (score 2):

Q: ***"How to tell Ansible to use 3.7"***

A: It's not possible to select the version of Python the `ansible*` utilities are running on. This version of Python depends on how the Ansible utilities(package) were built. This is the **python version** the utilities will display

```ini
shell> ansible --version
ansible [core 2.14.1]
  config file = /export/scratch/tmp7/test-206/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/admin/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/admin/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/admin/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages
  executable location = /home/admin/.local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.9.16 (main, Dec  7 2022, 01:11:51) [GCC 9.4.0] (/usr/bin/python3.9)
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True
```

The utilities below will display the same

```ini
shell> ansible-playbook --version
shell> ansible-inventory --version
...
```

There may be more versions of Python installed both on the controller and on the remote hosts. It's a complex process of how Ansible selects which version of Python will be used to execute the modules on a remote host. See:

- [Interpreter Discovery](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html#interpreter-discovery): *"Unless configured otherwise, Ansible will attempt to discover a suitable Python interpreter on each target host."*
- [INTERPRETER_PYTHON](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#interpreter-python): *"Configuration options how to select Python on the remote hosts."*
- [Debugging modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/debugging.html#debugging-modules) to learn details on how the Ansible modules are executed on a remote host.
- [Setting the Python interpreter in BSD](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/os_guide/intro_bsd.html#setting-the-python-interpreter)

It's necessary to understand that Ansible can manage both remote hosts and localhost. For example, on the controller (localhost), this *ansible* utility uses *python version = 3.9.16*. The version of Python to execute the modules may be different.

```bash
shell> ls -1 /usr/bin | egrep '^python[2,3]\.[0-9]$'
python2.7
python3.8
python3.9
```

By default, Ansible 'discovered' */usr/bin/python3* in Ubuntu which is a link to *python3.8*

```yaml
shell> ansible localhost -m setup | grep -i python
        "ansible_python": {
            "executable": "/usr/bin/python3",
            "type": "cpython",
        "ansible_python_version": "3.8.5",
        "ansible_selinux_python_present": true,
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3",
```

```bash
shell> ll /usr/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Apr 27  2020 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.8*
```

You can configure [*INTERPRETER_PYTHON*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#interpreter-python) in many different ways:

a) In the variable *ansible_python_interpreter* on the command line

```yaml
shell> ansible localhost -m setup -e ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3.9  | grep -i python
        "ansible_python": {
            "executable": "/usr/bin/python3.9",
            "type": "cpython",
        "ansible_python_version": "3.9.16",
        "ansible_selinux_python_present": true,
```

, but you can declare the variable in other precedence and in various scopes. See [Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable). You can even configure different versions for single tasks. For example,

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
        
  tasks:

    - command: "echo {{ ansible_python_interpreter }}"
      register: out
      vars:
        ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3.8
    - debug:
        var: out.stdout

    - command: "echo {{ ansible_python_interpreter }}"
      register: out
      vars:
        ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3.9
    - debug:
        var: out.stdout
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
TASK [command] ***********************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  out.stdout: /usr/bin/python3.8

TASK [command] ***********************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  out.stdout: /usr/bin/python3.9
```

---

b) In the environment variable ANSIBLE_PYTHON_INTERPRETER on the command line

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_PYTHON_INTERPRETER=/usr/bin/python3.9 ansible localhost -m setup  | grep -i python
        "ansible_python": {
            "executable": "/usr/bin/python3.9",
            "type": "cpython",
        "ansible_python_version": "3.9.16",
        "ansible_selinux_python_present": true,
```

c) In the configuration

```ini
shell> grep -B 1 interpreter_python ansible.cfg
[defaults]
interpreter_python = /usr/bin/python3.9
```

```yaml
shell> ansible localhost -m setup  | grep -i python
        "ansible_python": {
            "executable": "/usr/bin/python3.9",
            "type": "cpython",
        "ansible_python_version": "3.9.16",
        "ansible_selinux_python_present": true,
```

d) In the inventory for a single host

```ini
shell> cat hosts
localhost ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3.9
```

```yaml
shell> ansible localhost -m setup  | grep -i python
        "ansible_python": {
            "executable": "/usr/bin/python3.9",
            "type": "cpython",
        "ansible_python_version": "3.9.16",
        "ansible_selinux_python_present": true,
```

e) In the inventory for a group of hosts

```ini
shell> cat hosts
[test]
test_11
test_12
test_13

[test:vars]
ansible_user=admin
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/python3.8
```

```yaml
shell> ansible test_11 -m setup  | grep -i python
        "ansible_python": {
            "executable": "/usr/local/bin/python3.8",
            "type": "cpython",
        "ansible_python_version": "3.8.12",
            "status": "Missing selinux Python library"
        "ansible_selinux_python_present": false,
```

Answer (score 2):

To let ansible use the python version other than what it is taking by default, you can use [`ansible.cfg`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_configuration.html) file inside the project root from where you are running `ansible-playbook` command.

This file is like a configuration file from which ansible picks up details when it executes a playbook.

Once of its configuration option is `interpreter_python` where you specify the executable path.

Let's do this step by step :

1. First find the executable path of the python version you would like ansible to use. e.g. if it is python 3.10, you would run `which python3.10` from your terminal. It will give you something like `/usr/local/bin/python3.10` in the output(which may change if you have it installed in a different directory).
2. Create a file called `ansible.cfg` in the project root from where you are running your playbooks and add following :

```
[defaults]
stdout_callback = debug
interpreter_python= /usr/local/bin/python3.10
```

3. Now when you run the playbooks from this directory, ansible will take the interpreter_python configuration and use python3.10

An important note that now if you run `ansible-playbook --version` it might still show you the older python version it was using. But when you execute the playbook, it will take the `ansible.cfg` file into account.