# Tell Ansible playbook what version of Python to use on remote hosts

Tags: python-3.x, ansible, ansible-awx

I have an Ansible Module that requires Python3.8 or higher to run.  We deploy our playbooks through AWX (managed by another team). is there a way to get AWX to run a specific version of python or is this something that needs to be addressed on the AWX side?

I've tried adding ansible_python_interpreter and interpreter_python to my ansible.cfg, added as vars, and added it to the module as a vars:

```
vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3.9
    interpreter_python: /usr/bin/python3.9
OR
      import_role:
        name: aviconfig
      vars:
        ansible_playbook_python: /usr/bin/python3.9
        interpreter_python: /usr/bin/python3.9
```

But when I look at the task in AWX I get the following error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Unable to import vmware.alb.avi_serviceenginegroup due to more than 255 arguments"
}
```

When in the AWX GUI, there is no drop down for "execution environment" that I read about.

Comment: Very probably, this error isn't related to the configuration of Python.

Comment: You say: `"I have an Ansible Module that requires Python3.8"`. Ansible modules are being executed on the remote hosts. As a consequence, if you ask `"What version of Python to use?"` means `"What version of Python to use on the remote hosts?"`. I edited the title. JFYI, there is a 'hard-coded' Python version used by the Ansible utilities (ansible, ansible-playbook, ansible-inventory, ansible-config, ....). You can't configure this.

Answer (score 1):

See [INTERPRETER_PYTHON](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#interpreter-python). Quote:

> Path to the Python interpreter to be used for module execution on **remote targets**, ...

- *ansible_python_interpreter* is a variable
- *interpreter_python* is a configuration key used in ansible.cfg

When you declare the variables

```yaml
vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3.9
    interpreter_python: /usr/bin/python3.9
```

The modules will use */usr/bin/python3.9* on the remote hosts. The variable *interpreter_python* doesn't influence anything. This can be used in a configuration file. See [Configuring Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_configuration.html#configuring-ansible).

```ini
shell> cat ansible.cfg
[defaults]
interpreter_python = /usr/bin/python3.9
...
```

Generally, you can declare variables for a [play, role, block, and task](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#playbook-keywords). For example, declare the Python version for each task

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: test_14

  tasks:

    - ping:
      vars:
        ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/local/bin/python3.7

    - ping:
      vars:
        ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/local/bin/python3.8

    - ping:
      vars:
        ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/local/bin/python3.9
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -vvv | grep /usr/local/bin/python
```

> <10.1.0.17> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="asadmin"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o 'ControlPath="/export/home/vlado.config/.ansible/cp/d6c0760925"' -tt 10.1.0.17 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S -n  -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-qbxxhglwszmqjmslnpbuxgocmzxfidxv ; ***/usr/local/bin/python3.7*** /home/asadmin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1680757723.166957-1264442-114878406354546/AnsiballZ_ping.py'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''

> <10.1.0.17> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="asadmin"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o 'ControlPath="/export/home/vlado.config/.ansible/cp/d6c0760925"' -tt 10.1.0.17 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S -n  -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-vhudpllaaigkgxbwegttypeoavwuljwc ; ***/usr/local/bin/python3.8*** /home/asadmin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1680757724.7586734-1264451-30500526050593/AnsiballZ_ping.py'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''

> <10.1.0.17> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="asadmin"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o 'ControlPath="/export/home/vlado.config/.ansible/cp/d6c0760925"' -tt 10.1.0.17 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S -n  -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-thetuokxemcxduldbrtcipfitzucsytj ; ***/usr/local/bin/python3.9*** /home/asadmin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1680757726.1293967-1264468-188410557208290/AnsiballZ_ping.py'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''

See [Ansible is using wrong version of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61257164/ansible-is-using-wrong-version-of-python).